# Deserializing JSON responses which contain attributes that conflict with keywords

Tags: c#, json, json.net

There is an API which I don't control, but whose output I need to consume with C#, preferably using JSON.Net.

Here's an example response:

```
[
    {
        "media_id": 36867, 
        "explicit": 0
    }
]
```

I had planned to have a class like so:

```
class Media {
    public int media_id;
    public int explicit;
}
```

And to deserialize:

```
var l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Media>>(s);
```

Unfortunately, "explicit" is a C# keyword, so this can't compile.

My next guess is to modify the class:

```
class Media {
    public int media_id;
    public int explicit_;
}
```

... and somehow map the response attributes to the C# attributes.

How should I do that, or am I totally going at this the wrong way?

Failing that, I'd be OK to just plain ignore the "explicit" in the response, if there's a way to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Haven't used JSON.Net, but judging by the docs [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationAttributes.html), I figure you just need to do what you'd do with XmlSerialization: Add an attribute to tell how the JSON property should be called:

```
class Media {
    [JsonProperty("media_id")]
    public int MediaId;
    [JsonProperty("explicit")]
    public int Explicit;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I skipped over that one because the ToC said "serialization" when I wanted deserialization.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 12):

C# lets you define members with reserved word names (for interoperability cases exactly like this) by escaping them with an @, e.g.,

```
class Media {
    public int media_id;
    public int @explicit;
}
```

Not sure how this plays with JSON.Net, but I would imagine it should work (since the @ is an escape and not actually part of the field name).

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but can you provide a link to further explanation?  I tried this w/ that change: "var x = new Media(); x.explicit = true;" Wouldn't compile, but "x.@explicit = true" did.

Comment: In your code, you would use "@explicit". But this gets compiled to an actual name of "explicit" in the binary. So the JSON.Net serialization/deserialization code would see "explicit", not "@explicit". Just like when you use "\n" in your code, but it gets compiled into a linefeed in the binary.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Still accepted the JsonProperty answer, since it is specific to this domain and handles more general cases as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me.

```
class JsonRpc {
  public string id;
  public string method;
  public string[] @params;
}
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonRpc> (data)
```

Thanks everyone