# How to force camelcase with JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible?

I have a class like this:

```
public class ABC
{
    [Key]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string AnotherField { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

But I would like to serialize like this `{ "name":"foo", "anotherField":"bar" }` instead of 
 `{ "Name":"foo", "AnotherField":"bar" }`.

This is how I use:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj));
```

Comment: Should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671044/deserializing-json-responses-which-contain-attributes-that-conflict-with-keyword. And yes, it obviously means you have to leave the inbuilt serializer.

Comment: If you are using JSON.NET it has a `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization for an example with Web.Api

Comment: This may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040838/mvc-jsonresult-camelcase-serialization

Answer (score -6):

You can use a camel case resolver from Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
On you global.asax you register it on application start

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

protected void Application_Start()
{
     config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't apply to the JavaScriptSerializer, unfortunately.