# object to deserialize has a C# keyword

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization, keyword

With the JSON defined as it is, in order to deserialize it as an object, I'd need to create a property on my class called "event", which is a C# keyword.  Is there another way to tell it what the field names will be?

Here's an example of the JSON:

> {    event: 123 data:
>   {"data":"0D0401","ttl":"60","published_at":"2014-04-16T18:04:42.446Z","id":"48ff6f065067555031192387"}
>   }

Here are my classes that won't compile because of the keyword:

```
public class Event
{
    public int event { get; set; }
    public EventDetail data { get; set; }
}

public class EventDetail
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string ttl { get; set; }
    public DateTime published_at { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try putting a @ sign at the beginning of identifier `public int @event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `[DataContract(Name = "@event")]` attribute on the relevant property.  Then it will (de)serialize correctly, and you can rename the property so that it compiles.

Comment: But then I'd have to include the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace, which wouldn't be needed otherwise.  Are the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes supported by `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: I believe so. I've used them myself in code for calling REST APIs, and I believe that the HTTP Client libraries use `Newtonsoft.Json` under the covers.

Comment: Hey, that's cool. It works like you said.  Not sure what you mean about HTTP...  I'm just using `Event obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>(string)` to deserialize it.

Comment: Never mind about HTTP Client, as long as it works :)

Comment: Even better, I find that I can use the JsonProperty attribute to define the field name, as in this post: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671044/deserializing-json-responses-which-contain-attributes-that-conflict-with-keyword.  And I don't need to #include the Serialization namespace.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
public class Event
{
    public int event { get; set; }
    public EventDetail data { get; set; }
}
```

to this

```
public class Event
{
    public int @event { get; set; }
    public EventDetail data { get; set; }
}
```

This tip shows the quirks involved with escaping in C#:

- **character literal escaping**:

> e.g. '\'', '\n', '\u20AC' (the Euro € currency sign), '\x9'

(equivalent to \t))
- **literal string escaping:**

> e.g. "...\t...\u0040...\U000000041...\x9..."

- **verbatim string escaping:**

> e.g. @"...""..."

- **string.Format escaping:**

> e.g. "...{{...}}..."

- **keyword escaping:**

> e.g. @if (for if as identifier)

- **identifier escaping:**

> e.g. i\u0064 (for id)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to just capitalize the "e", and it still works.  Looks like the parsing mechanism is case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Just in any case someone revisits this...
in DotNet 3.1 `using System.Text.Json.Serialization` use the attribute

```
[JsonPropertyName("TheNameItHasInJsonFile")]
public int Something {get;set;}
```