# Sending C# Reserved Word as Property of PostData Api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I have some `JSON` that i am sending over to my `C#` `API` and it looks like the following

```
 {
  "currency": "BTC",
  "amount": "0.00049659",
  "type": "bankToExchange"
 }
```

The issue is when the model arrives in my controller, the `type` property is changed to `@type` which is making the post request fail.

The API I am trying to connect to uses `type`, so this cannot be changed. The post works in `Postman`, so **is there a work around for this?**

Answer (score 0):

Add the DataMember name property on your type using [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm):

```
[DataMember(Name = "@type")] //if not using NewtonSoft
[JsonProperty("@type")] //if using NewtonSoft
public string type { get; set; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Data member attribute with property name. You can use by creating class for your json, as follows

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Sample{
         [DataMember(Name = "@type")]
         public string Type{get;set;}
    }
```

You can try with another approach as well, which is elegant and more meaning full if **you add comment for appending @ before property name** :

```
     public class Sample{
             public string @type{get;set;}
        }
```

For reference: [object to deserialize has a C# keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116995/object-to-deserialize-has-a-c-sharp-keyword)

Comment: so im sending it to a 3rd party api, so this doesnt seem to be working

Comment: which option is not working, the second one? Have you tried with first one. @Sadique already suggested if you are using Newton.Json for deserializing, then you can use JsonProperty. If 3rd party API is public, then please let me know endpoints, I can try by my own.